# How to get state value with dynamic parameter?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to access a value from my state, which looks like like the following :

```
this.state = {
  provider: {
    NameFr: "",
    NameEn: ""
  }
}
```

I've two inputs in my HTML code, one for the french value and the other one for the english value.

I have a function which renders the input itself :

```
const name = "Name" + ((lang === "en") ? "En" : "Fr");

return (
  <input
    maxlength={longTextboxLength} 
    cssClass="longTextbox" 
    name={name} 
    value={value}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    readOnly={this.props.readonly} 
  />
)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the `name` constant and pass it to something like `this.state.provider.name`. But, obviously, it won't work.

I also tried to use the parameter as an array item : `this.state.provider[name]`, but it doesn't work neither.

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I wasn't updating properly my state. Fixed now, using `this.state.provider[name]`.